# Create Columns off of row number

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    t.RN, t.[value]
FROM
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN, 
         *
     FROM
         (SELECT value 
          FROM STRING_SPLIT('1.16.8.20220812.2.961', '.')) z
    ) t
```

It basically returns a table like this because I want the columns to be labeled as something specific like, date, or serial number

| RN | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

I would like be able to make it into something like this

| lable1 | label2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |

I figure pivoting the table would be the way to go but I'm unsure on how to do this

Comment: Will there always be a fixed and known number of columns?  Or, at least, a maximum number of columns?  *(SQL is strongly and statically typed, individual queries can't varying different numbers of columns, and trying to do so is often a code-smell.)*

Comment: yes the columns will be a fixed number of 6

Answer (score 2):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` won't guarantee that the items come back in the correct order.

Normally they will, but it's not guaranteed, which would be a nightmare bug to fight.

Instead, make use of JSON's arrays...

```
SELECT
  JSON_VALUE(json_string, '$[0]')   AS label0,
  JSON_VALUE(json_string, '$[1]')   AS label1,
  JSON_VALUE(json_string, '$[2]')   AS label2,
  JSON_VALUE(json_string, '$[3]')   AS label3,
  JSON_VALUE(json_string, '$[4]')   AS label4,
  JSON_VALUE(json_string, '$[5]')   AS label5
FROM
(
  SELECT
    CONCAT('[', REPLACE('1.16.8.20220812.2.961', '.', ','), ']')  AS json_string
)
  AS example
```

[DB<>FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91cd0607fdb94a08f2ac9a29a58fcda5)

***EDIT:*** Re-added the Azure SQL option *(Should also work in SQL Server 2022 when released)*

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN ordinal = 1 THEN value END)   AS label1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ordinal = 2 THEN value END)   AS label2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ordinal = 3 THEN value END)   AS label3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ordinal = 4 THEN value END)   AS label4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ordinal = 5 THEN value END)   AS label5,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ordinal = 6 THEN value END)   AS label6
FROM
  STRING_SPLIT('1.16.8.20220812.2.961', '.', 1)
```

Comment: the first example you had worked and was much easier to understand, thank you. the row number was only to give me something to attach to the values, using string split puts them in the correct order

Answer (score 1):

You were actually on the right path. A [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) clause gives you the required transformation, and as you can see you can also remove one level of nesting from your original query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT  value
           ,'label' + cast (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as varchar(10))  AS label
         
     FROM    STRING_SPLIT('1.16.8.20220812.2.961', '.') ss
    ) t
     pivot (max(value) for label in (label1,label2,label3,label4,label5,label6)) p
```

| label1 | label2 | label3 | label4 | label5 | label6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 8 | 20220812 | 2 | 961 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b9dbfeb0469c86213ceb412713ed051)